# Can't run a function x times

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run a function to move a imageView x times. This is a walking animation.

```
public void doWalk() {
    String mDrawableName = buddy.leraar.naam;
    if (buddy.gezondheid < 30)
    {
        mDrawableName += "_dik_lopen";
    }
    else if (buddy.gezondheid > 85)
    {
        mDrawableName += "_dun_lopen";
    }
    else {
        mDrawableName += "_medium_lopen";
    }
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(resID);
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            executeWalk(rnd.nextInt(1));
        };
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 300);
}


public void executeWalk(int left) {
    if (rolls < 10)
    {
        rolls++;
        if (left == 0)
        {
            imageView.setX(imageView.getLeft() - 10);
        }
        else {
            imageView.setX(imageView.getLeft() + 10);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the executeWalk function seems to get called only once, while it should run every 300 milliseconds. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, even after looking at alot of different examples.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long). The problem is that you start your function in delay 300ms only one time.

```
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 300);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_timer.htm) the overload of schedule you are using is `void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)` so you are just delaying the execution of the task but not performing it periodically. You should use `void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` to schedule the timer to execute something periodically.

So it should be something like:

`timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 300);`

Answer (score 1):

`timer.schedule(timerTask, 300);` will run the task just once, and the task will run in 300 milliseconds.

In order to repeat the execution you must use :

`void schedule (TimerTask task, Date firstTime,  long period)`

Where the **period** is the delay between executions.

`timer.schedule(timerTask, 300, 100);` will run the task the first time in 300 milliseconds and later the task will be launch every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for your response, for some reason my code still only runs once. I guess have another problem

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an AsyncTask for this.
Extend AsyncTask within the same activity class (make the imageview(s) a class variable)

```
public class MoveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        while(1) {
            delay(300);
            publishProgress();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... voids)
    {
        //Move the imageview here
        executeWalk(rnd.nextInt(1));
    }
}
```

Then in doWalk() make an instance and execute the AsyncTask:

```
MoveTask moveTask=new MoveTask();
MoveTask.execute();
```